# I wonder whats happens when if(i%2) what does it checks to come to continue. It misses == but it prints out the sum as 20? Why?

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, for-loop, continue

```
#import <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int sum,i;
    sum = 0;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
        if(i%2)
            continue;
        sum+=i;
    }
    printf("\n%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

How does `if(i%2)` works in the above code?

Comment: `if(i%2)` is equivalent to `if(i%2 != 0)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another (sometimes called modulus).% is the modulus operator.

So i%2 returns the remainder left after i is divided by 2.
Therefore if i is odd i%2=1(TRUE)
else it is 0(FALSE).(even condition)

Therefore if i is even i is added to sum else the loop continues.

Comment: Is 0 some true statement in the if(i%2)

Comment: In C true is represented by any numeric value not equal to 0 and false is represented by 0.@user3704516

Answer (score 0):

Here, the `%` used is called the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). It checks the remainder of a division.

Regarding the `if` statement, the `C11` standard says, from chapter `§6.8.4.1`

> **Syntax** : `if` ( *expression* ) statement

and

> ... the first sub-statement is executed if the expression compares unequal to 0.

So, for a statement like `if(i%2)`, the result

- is TRUE, when the `i` value is not a multiple of 2, i.e., produces a non-zero remainder, so `continue;` is encountered.
- is FALSE, when `i` is perfectly divisible by 2. so, `continue;` is skipped and 
  `sum+=i;` is executed.

**That said,** there is no `#import <stdio.h>` in `C`, it should be `#include <stdio.h>`

Finaly,

> *How does if(i%2) works in the above code?*

It is used to add all the *even* numbers up to 9. The result, `20`, is then printed out.

Comment: But in the if statements what does become true in the if statements

Comment: @user3704516 sorry i did not understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the if statement

```
if ( i % 2 )
```

is equivalent to

```
if ( i % 2 != 0 )
```

This condition is equal to true if i is an odd number. 
So the program finds the sum of even numbers in the range `[0, 10 )`

According to the C Standard (6.8.4.1 The if statement)

> 2 In both forms, the first substatement is executed **if the
>   expression compares unequal to 0**.

Here "the first substatement" means the if statement (if else is present then it is the second substatement).

It is better to rewrite the loop without the break statement. For example

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
{
    if ( i % 2 == 0 ) sum += i;
}
```

It is the same as

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i += 2 )
{
    sum += i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if condition knows only `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

If your `modulo` operation make a `true` condition then it will execute `continue`. Otherwise it will do sum.

**True condition = any number without zero(0)